# Why Bell-LaPadula simple and star properties are named that way?

Tags: bell-lapadula

In Bell LaPadula model, there are 2 properties:

- *** (star)** properties: No write down
- **Simple** properties: No read up

I can understand *no write down* and *no read up*, which is very descriptive.

However why are those properties also named **"*"** and **Simple**? The naming conversion doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: You'll have to ask Bell or LaPadula.

Comment: Have you looked up the original papers? They do explain the choices to some level.

Comment: *Have you looked up the original papers* No I haven't, and to me it seems very hard to find the original paper. From other source like `https://www.acsac.org/2005/papers/Bell.pdf` also didn't describe why the naming convension.

Comment: Ah I have found part of the answer from in one of the video in https://www.cybrary.it/ from Kelly. She said from the research she done, Bell and Lapadula are thinking of a good name for the "no write down" properties but cannot think of a good name. Therefore, they just put a * in the field for placeholder. In the end, no better name come up and they stuck with the * properties...